# Pre commit hook checks for source lint (not staged)

Tags: git, angular-cli, husky

The idea of git hooks is for preventing the wrong source code from being committed. I use `husky` for this purpose. Here is my setting:

```json
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "ng lint --fix=true"
  }
}
```

If there is a lint error, it prevents from being committed. Here is the scenario:

1. Developer writes wrong code (e.g. `x==y` which should be `x===y` from lint point of view)
2. He uses these commands: `git add .` and `git commit -m "msg here"` which fails. Because lint fails.
3. He corrects the source code. But instead of doing `git add .` again, he uses this command: `git commit -m "msg here"`. This time lint doesn't fail, because in source code everything is fine, and `ng lint` succeeds. But actually, he is committing the previous version which has been added before.

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: pre commit hooks are terrible ideas. You should not be doing code quality checks when doing a commit. Quality checks should be done in the PR phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lint-staged`](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) is what you are looking for.

It will only lint the staged files, which is really efficient.

That means that it would force the developer in your example to stage the fix before `lint-staged` will accept it.

Put this in your *package.json* file:

```json
{ 
   ...
   "devDependencies": {
       "lint-staged": "^10.5.1",
       ...
   }
   ...
   "husky": {
       "hooks": {
           "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. And one question. Is it compatible with my `tslint.json` file in my Angular project?

Comment: @VahidNajafi Yes, you can configure it to use eslint for ts files. You do that by creating a .lintstagedrc file with the following content: `module.exports = { '*.{ts}': 'eslint --fix...' }`. See https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#configuration and  https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#what-commands-are-supported

Comment: @VahidNajafi did my comment answer your question? :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough time to check it. I will check and let you know. Thanks